# How to make function or macros for any count of arguments with any types?

Tags: c++, c++11, macros

There are client and server. I send and receive data using `boost::serialization`. Often several arguments with different types send. Are there ways to make function or macros for this?

For example `send(argType1, argType2, argType3);`

I think i will not send more then 5 arguments for one time.

-

Here is my version

```
template<class T>
int sendData(SSL *ssl, int command, T t)
{
    std::string serialData;
    OByteStream obs(serialData);
    obs << command;
    obs << t;
    obs.flush();

    return SSL_write(ssl, &serialData[0], BUF_SIZE);
}

template<class T1, class T2>
int sendData(SSL *ssl, int command, T1 t1, T2 t2)
{
    std::string serialData;
    OByteStream obs(serialData);
    obs << command;
    obs << t1;
    obs << t2;
    obs.flush();

    return SSL_write(ssl, &serialData[0], BUF_SIZE);
}

template<class T1, class T2, class T3>
int sendData(SSL *ssl, int command, T1 t1, T2 t2, T3 t3)
{
    std::string serialData;
    OByteStream obs(serialData);
    obs << command;
    obs << t1;
    obs << t2;
    obs << t3;
    obs.flush();

    return SSL_write(ssl, &serialData[0], BUF_SIZE);
}

...
```

Comment: It's hard to understand what you're asking. Perhaps you should read a tutorial on macros and then explain specifically what point it didn't address.

Answer (score 0):

If you read the tutorial, you will find out that the idea behind most serializers is is that anywhere the aplication defined types and objects are described. That is for boost something like:

```
class xyz
{
    int a;
    std::string b;
    std::vector<int> c;

    ...
    Serialization_Method(serializer_type &ser)
    {
       ser & a;
       ser & b;
       ser & c;
    }
}
```

That ends to the possibility, that you can serialize your types with:

```
ser & xyz_obj;
```

If you can define your objects with your serialization method, you can indirectly send/receive all data you need. The description is always done in one of the serialisation methods.

Your idea to send "anything" without any description will never work and can never work. That is simply because your receiver must have an idea where to put the data in. If you think a program fragment on the receiver side and we think that we can receive "something". How should we proceed with that kind of data? Your code must have at least the knowledge of the classes and objects which are represented by your code AND the cosponsoring data. If you receive "some undefined" data, you are not able to work with this data! That ends in the definition of data and serialization structures on both sides. For boost, that is simply done with the `serializer_obj & serializer_data;` statements.